# how to pass php post method string in javascript parameter function?

Tags: javascript, php, post

The javascript cannot redirect when the `subId` value is a letter but if it is a number it works fine.

here's my code

```
if($sql_update==true){


         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

                function alertAndRedirect(subId) {
                    alert('Updated');
                    window.location = '?tag=subject_entry&opr=upd&rs_id='+subId;
                }


                alertAndRedirect(".$_POST['sub_code_txt'].");
                </script>";

    }
```

the variable `subId` only accepts integer or number from the post method `alertAndRedirect(".$_POST['sub_code_txt'].");`. How can I let javascript accept the string id so that I can redirect?

Comment: where is you javascript code where you are calling method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose in single quotes :

```
alertAndRedirect('".$_POST['sub_code_txt']."');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your value in quotes `'...'`:

```
alertAndRedirect('".$_POST['sub_code_txt']."');
```

Otherwise it will show up as:

```
alertAndRedirect(valueOfItem)
```

You want it to be enclosed in quotes for text values:

```
alertAndRedirect('valueOfItem')
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the given answers are correct. Just added an enhancement in my answer to avoid a possible error. The posted variable may also contains single or double quotes so adding slashes would be a better handling.

```
alertAndRedirect('".addcslashes($_POST['sub_code_txt'])."');
```